# AWS already made EC2 instance and forgot to create port 5000

Tags: amazon-web-services, web

I need a port for my ec2 instance, and I only have ports 80 443 22 and 8080 in the security group. Is there any port one can use that doesn't require to be put in the security group?
Thanks!

Comment: You can modify existing SG to add the new port.

Comment: How does one do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add new port:

#### 1. In `Security` tab for your instance, click the security group of interest:

[image]

#### 2. In the `Inbound rules` click `Edit inbound rules`

[image]

#### 3. Add your port 5000 as the security group as per your requirenments

[image]

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you! I read somewhere else that it couldn't be done and was about to restart my whole instance!